# Stroking a path only inside/outside?

Tags: qt, qpainter

Given a [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) how can I stroke the path only on the inside or outside edge of the path (or left- or right-side for non-closed paths)?

[`QPainter::strokePath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#strokePath) centers the pen along the path and causes the same amount of ink to fall on both sides. For a visual example of the desired effect, see this graphic I made (for an SVG proposal, not feature):

[image: SVG proposed stroke-location example, from phrogz.net/SVG/stroke-location.svg]

I don't mind if this is done through some hack like setting the path itself as a clipping region (for inside) or anti-clipping region (for outside).

*The goal here is to fill a rounded rectangle with a low-opacity fill and then stroke just outside that with a lower-opacity stroke to simulate a 2-step 'blur' falloff. If the stroke overlaps the fill then the opacity is doubled, ruining the effect. Due to the complex shape a simple scaling of the path would not work well, even though it might work for the circles and rectangles drawn above.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [`QPainterPathStroker`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainterpathstroker.html). Use it to create a new path that's the outline of your path. Then use QPainterPath operations like intersection or subtraction between the two:

```
outsidePath = strokedPath.subtracted(originalPath);
insidePath = strokedPath.intersected(originalPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to set the blending mode to `CompositionMode_Source`:

```cpp
QPainter * painter;
painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
painter->setPen(QPen{color, stroke, ...});
painter->setBrush(QBrush{...});

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(...);
path.lineTo(...);
...

// No alpha composition issues
painter->fillPath();
```